# Active Directory user unable to access desktop and my Documents when out of our office domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008

One of our office user needs to take his computer home to work and obviously he is out of our office domain. He is able to logon to his domain account but couldn't see his desktop and my documents. Refresh the desktop will see the error:

```
\\nydc1\..\..... is not accessible. You might not have permission to use the network resource.
```

The weird thing is we have another user that needs to do the same thing but able to see his cached version of desktop and my documents when working from home. Of course both users belong to the same domain, and both machine own a fresh install of Window 7 Professional.

Is there a group policy or setting that I need to configure on my domain controller? Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: OK I figured. This is actually not an AD problem. The user's computer doesn't have offline file access enabled in Control Panel. Once that is enabled he is able to access file offline now.

Comment: Please post the solution as a new answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured. This is actually not an AD problem. The user's computer doesn't have offline file access enabled in Control Panel. Once that is enabled he is able to access file offline now.